# Ruby regex select without a [

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to select letter without **[** in my log(meassage1).

**My Log:**

```
 [LogMessage:INFO:[sm-Server-02110] Product=PolicyServer,Platform=Linux 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64,Version=12.52,Update=01.01,Label=640,Crypto=128,UTC=1456285048,TZ=0][]
```

**My Regex:**

```
 \[(?<message1>\S+)\]\s(?<message2>.*)\]\[(?<data>[^\]]*)\]$
```

**Matches:**

```
message1    LogMessage:INFO:[sm-Server-02110
message2    Product=PolicyServer,Platform=Linux    2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64,Version=12.52,Update=01.01,Label=640,Crypto=128,UTC=1456285048,TZ=0
data
```

**Reference:**  http://rubular.com/r/urCvQMdRlB

I need to match result `message1   LogMessage:INFO:sm-Server-02110` instead of `message1  LogMessage:INFO:[sm-Server-02110`

**I tried below way:**

```
\[(?<message1>[^[].*)\]\s(?<message2>.*)\]\[(?<data>[^\]]*)\]$
```

but its throw **Premature end of char-class.**

Suggest me How to select value with out select this.

Comment: Just remove it from `message1` after you get the match. There is no way to capture non-continuous parts of texts into 1 group.

Comment: Another way would be to match `LogMessage:INFO:` and `sm-Server-02110` separately and concatenate them afterwards.

Comment: @mudasobwa: If you have time, please post an answer showing this approach. Or maybe both.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done

Answer (score 4):

The answer below is posted by Wiktor Stribiżew’s request in comments.

**There is no way to capture non-continuous parts of texts into 1 group.** Hence, we have two different possibilities:

1. (by Wiktor Stribiżew):

```
input = "[LogMessage:INFO:[sm-Server-02110] Product=Policy"
input =~ /^\[(?<message1>\S+)\]\s(?<message2>.*)$/
[$~[:message1].delete('['), $~[:message2]]
#⇒ [
#    [0] "LogMessage:INFO:sm-Server-02110",
#    [1] "Product=Policy"
# ]
```

2. (by mudasobwa):

```
input =~ /^\[(?<message1_1>.+?)\[(?<message1_2>.+?)\]\s(?<message2>.*)$/
[$~[:message1_1] + $~[:message1_2], $~[:message2]]
#⇒ [
#    [0] "LogMessage:INFO:sm-Server-02110",
#    [1] "Product=Policy"
# ]
```